# exec not working in php script ( WAMP Server )

Tags: php, exec, wamp

I am using WAMP server on my system to execute php scripts.

I want to execute a script `test.php` from my main script `main.php`.

For that I am  using `exec` function like this `exec('php test.php');`. In `test.php` I have given one `echo` statement.

But when I run my `main.php` script from the browser I am not able to see output of `test.php` script.

What am I doing wrong ? please suggest.

Comment: You need to give the full path where the php installed in your wamp server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give the proper path of `php.exe`

```
exec("c:\wamp\<where ever you exe is>/php.exe test.php");
```

so it has to be a proper path

Comment: @rohitarora....yeah it worked..thanks.. Can I set this path in the environment variable. and use only `php` here ?

Answer (score 1):

use this command

```
echo exec('php test.php', $output);  //this will print your echo statement.
print_r($output);
```

Comment: @Mayank the second parameter stores the output of the command in $output variable.